# Простейшее объединение таблиц в R

Tags: r, таблицы

Помогите просто соединить две таблицы в одну. Т.е. добавить строки одной таблицы в другую. 
Таблица 1 
имя номер   оценка
Лена    12  8
Света   3   7
Петя    4   6
Игорь   5   9

Таблица 2 
имя номер   оценка
Дима    7   6
Коля    15  8
Илья    9   7

Надо получить Таблица 3
имя номер   оценка
Лена    12  8
Света   3   7
Петя    4   6
Игорь   5   9
Дима    7   6
Коля    15  8
Илья    9   7

Answer (score 1):

Вот:

```
df3 <- rbind(df1, df2)
```